# RxJava 2 - Observable.flatMapSingle clarification

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I did an **RxJava2** experiment consisting of the following steps:

1. Create an Observable from a **ListA** of Objects.
2. Use [flatMapSingle()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#flatMapSingle-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) to map each item emitted by the Observable, to a SingleSource. Inside flatMapSingle(), **an asychronous operation is executed for each item emitted by the Observable**.
3. Collected all items in a **ListB**, with [Observable.toList()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#toList--)

Result: **ListB** has its items in different order than **ListA** due to the asynchronous operation.

So, it seems that flatMapSingle() works like [flatMap()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#flatMap-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) in the sense that it uses the merge operator and does not guarantee that the order of the elements will be preserved.

Is my conclusion correct? Documentation did not cover me and discussions about this behavior are nonexistent.

Comment: By convention, `flatMap` does not guarantee ordering of the output events in respect to the input value that was mapped into the sources.

Comment: Thank you for the immediate respond. Docs are pretty clear about `flatMap` and it's as you stated. I just wanted to confirm that the same applies to `flatMapSingle` (yeah, the name has flatMap in it, but better safe than sorry...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`flatMap` doesn't guarantee ordering as @akarnokd mentioned in the comment.

If you want to guarantee ordering you can use `concatMap` but it allows you to only concatenate with inner `Observable`. It seems there is no version of `concatMapSingle` in both RxJava1 and RxJava2. You, however, can workaround it by converting inner `Single` to `Observable` using `toObservable()` by yourself and use it with `concatMap` like this (code written in Kotlin).

```
Observable
    .fromIterable(listA)
    .concatMap { single.toObservable() }
    .toList() // Items in the list has same order of listA
```

Note that there is also `concatMapEager` that will eagerly subscribe to an inner `Observable` (or `Single` in the above example) that may help improve parallelize tasks.